# How can I prevent `pdflatex` logs to created?

Tags: auctex

Following [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/65076/18414) is used as base to compile current buffer that is a `LaTeX` file:

```lisp
(defun my-run-latex ()
  "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((inhibit-message t)
         (TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
         (TeX-clean-confirm t)
         (TeX-save-query nil)
         (master (TeX-master-file))
         (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master))))
    (TeX-save-document master)
    (when (and (processp process)
               (eq (process-status process) 'run))
      (delete-process process))
    (TeX-command-master)))

(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode %S%(PDFout)")))  ;; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161303/127048
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (λ ()
                             (TeX-fold-mode 1)))
```

Here even I have `-interaction=batchmode` flag, `AucTeX` adds `-interaction=nonstopmode`, which force to generated output during latex compilation. I want to suppress the generated compile logs to speed up the build process.

file name `*`:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `eblocbroker' with ``pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode  -interaction=nonstopmode work.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./work.tex
// generated compile log ...
```

How can I prevent `pdflatex` logs to be created or is there any way to suppress the logs or have lowest verbose outputs?

Comment: Redirect stderr and stdout to `/dev/null`

Comment: How can I re-direct it within the emacs? Could I write something like : `(setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode %S%(PDFout) >/dev/null 2>&1")))` ?

Comment: That's the first thing I'd try

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157242/adding-an-option-to-the-pdflatex-call-from-auctex

Comment: Seems like adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` worked! it still generates a file called `*` but having only `TeX Output finished at Thu Jun  9 21:57:15`. Also I keep seeing `LaTeX: problems after [0] pages` in the mini-buffer after the compiling

Comment: See also this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745908/avoiding-the-creation-of-aux-log-and-synctex-gz-files-when-using-pdflatex

Comment: @Ian seems like `-aux-directory=/some/temp/dir` change the created path of the aux folders .  `-interaction=batchmode` is the flag to prevent logs to generated but emacs add additional `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag that overwrite my configuration. If i can find a way emacs to not add `-interaction=nonstopmode` flag into the command could be the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search `nonstopmode` in the auctex code, you will find The `-interaction=nonstopmode` is expanded from the [`%(mode)`](https://github.com/emacs-straight/auctex/blob/master/tex.el#L563-L566) in the [`TeX-command-list`](https://github.com/emacs-straight/auctex/blob/master/tex.el#L187).

Here are three options you can inhibit `-interaction=nonstopmode`:

1. change how `%(mode)` expand in `TeX-expand-list`:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
             '("%(mode)"
               (lambda nil
                 (if TeX-interactive-mode ""
                   " -interaction=batchmode"))))
;; use extra-options to leave `LaTeX-command-style' not changed
(setq TeX-command-extra-options " -shell-escape")
```

2. change `TeX-command-list` directly:

```lisp
(setf (nth 1 (assoc "LaTeX" TeX-command-list)) "%`%l%' %T")
```

3. enable `TeX-interactive-mode`, i.e.:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-interactive-mode)
```

Comment: This opens a file that has `Running LaTeX on som.tex with pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode  some.tex'` text in it. The file opened as a  buffer in a half page windows ; is it possible to prevent it ? like I want window not to pop-up

Comment: It seems to be caused by TeX-interactive-mode, if you really want to remove `-interaction=nonstopmode` you can just modify `TeX-command-list` (see my updated answer).

Comment: Or change how `%(mode)` expand, i.e. `TeX-expand-list-builtin`.

Comment: Should I apply all the three options or if I apply the first one would it be enough?

Comment: Choose the one you like, I prefer the first one. And the last one have side effect you don't want.

Comment: I choose the first one :-) Thanks for the edit to the answer

Comment: By any chance do you get `LaTeX: problems after [0] pages` warning message?

Comment: I'm not using auctex recently, maybe you can open a new problem.