# How can I suppress "LaTeX: problems after [0] pages" message?

Tags: auctex

What I you try to do:

I am trying to compile a latex file (opened buffer) with the following command in order to suppress its compilation logs:

`pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode current_buffer.tex`

---

I keep seeing following message in the minibuffer when a tex file is compiled:

`LaTeX: problems after [0] pages`

I couldn't figure out why this error shows up even the tex file compiled successfully. Would it be possible to suppress this message?

---

Following [solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/65076/18414) is used as base to compile current buffer that is a `LaTeX` file with merge of the solution here: [How can I prevent `pdflatex` logs to created?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/72030/how-can-i-prevent-pdflatex-logs-to-created/72102?noredirect=1#comment117106_72102)

```lisp
(require 'package)
(setq user-init-file (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
(setq user-emacs-directory (file-name-directory user-init-file))

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(setq frame-background-mode 'dark)

(require 'tex)
(add-to-list 'TeX-expand-list
             '("%(mode)"
               (lambda nil
                 (if TeX-interactive-mode ""
                   " -interaction=batchmode"))))

(setq TeX-command-extra-options " -shell-escape")

(defun my-run-latex ()
  "Save all buffers and run LaTeX on the current master."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((inhibit-message t)
         (TeX-command-force "LaTeX")
         (TeX-clean-confirm t)
         (TeX-save-query nil)
         (master (TeX-master-file))
         (process (and (stringp master) (TeX-process master))))
    (TeX-save-document master)
    (when (and (processp process)
               (eq (process-status process) 'run))
      (delete-process process))
    (TeX-command-master)))

(setq LaTeX-item-indent 0)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook 'hl-todo-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'writegood-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
                             (TeX-global-PDF-mode t)))
```

Minimal `tex` file to open emacs with:

```tex
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) [forbidden sign,line width=2ex,draw=red,fill=white] {Smoking};
    \node [opacity=.5]   at (2,0) [forbidden sign,line width=2ex,draw=red,fill=white] {Smoking};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

---

- compile log:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `emacs' with ``pdflatex -shell-escape  -interaction=batchmode emacs.tex''
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
/Users/alper/venv/bin/pygmentize

TeX Output finished at Fri Jul  1 12:11:47
```

Question related to `LaTeX: problems after [0] pages` is asked here [Emacs gives me "Latex: problems after [0] pages"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232278/127048):  I have applied the following configuration, which did not helped.

> ```tex
> (add-to-list
>  'TeX-expand-list
>  (list "%(extraopts)"
>       (lambda nil TeX-command-extra-options)))
> ```

Comment: I imagine this is because `auctex` is looking inside the (mostly empty) compile log to see how the run went and is now confused.

Comment: What is your source code - i.e post a minimal example. What do you try to do - maybe something is missing (i.e. pygmentize)?

Comment: @Ian I have added the minimal example , updated what I try to do write-up . Please note that pygmentize is already installed

Comment: Your minimal tex-example is broken; there is `\begin{tikzpicture}` missing and even adding that doesn't fix it.  I took this from pgf manual and it works: `\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) [forbidden sign,line width=2ex,draw=red,fill=white] {Smoking};
  \node [opacity=.5]
  at (2,0) [forbidden sign,line width=2ex,draw=red,fill=white] {Smoking};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @ArashEsbati thanks I updated the tex section with the example code you shared

Comment: A simple google search leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46422528.  There are more hits when you search for above message.  I don't use latex or auctex.  I can't help beyond what google says.