# How can I save all buffers on auto-save except the ones have specifc mode?

Tags: hooks, auto-save

I am using following `full-auto-save ()` (https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave) to save all buffers on Auto-Save.

```lisp
(defun full-auto-save ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
      (set-buffer buf)
      (if (and (buffer-file-name) (buffer-modified-p))
          (basic-save-buffer)))))

(add-hook 'auto-save-hook 'full-auto-save)
```

I have a ~2000 lines of a `tex` file, where after each save I run `pdflatex` to compile my latex file in combination with emac's auto-backup feature. Hence in the backup auto-saving causes `pdflatex` to run every few second along with writing the large file as backup while I am typing, which leads Emacs to freeze.

Is it possible to prevent auto-save for specific modes disable it for a specific mode, such as `LaTeX-mode`, but keep it enabled for other modes?

Comment: Is it possible to not automatically run `pdflatex` when a PDF buffer is is autosaved, but only on a manual save? Possibly by checking that target file for '#' or checking the buffer-modified-p flag (which isn't cleared by autosaves, only manual saves, IIRC)

Comment: @CSM I was using following solution https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/65050/how-to-automatically-accept-please-answer-y-or-n-process-latex-for-document/65076#65076 in `after-save-hook`. I like to see changes right away on the pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, after the `set-buffer`, just add the condition using `unless` to only save a buffer 'when not' the major`mode is a member of the list of modes that you would like to exclude, as follows:

```lisp
(defun full-auto-save ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (dolist (buf (buffer-list))
      (set-buffer buf)
      (unless (memq major-mode '(latex-mode))
        (if (and (buffer-file-name) (buffer-modified-p))
            (basic-save-buffer))))))
```

This code excludes for `LaTeX-mode`, but you can add other modes to that list.

Comment: If I want to apply this multiple major modes , can I add their names into `major-mode '(LaTeX-mode)`?

Comment: Exactly! (see the last line of the answer)

Comment: Thanks, seperated by just space  right like `(memq major-mode '(LaTeX-mode git-commit-mode)`?

Comment: Yes (this is some text required to fill up this comment)

Comment: I have tried `LaTeX-mode` and `tex-mode`but both didn' prevent auto-save operation :-( Current major mode is `LaTeX/FP mode defined in ‘tex-mode.el’:` I am not sure what LaTeX/FP is referred to

Comment: Try `C-h v` `major-mode` in that LaTeX/FP buffer to find the name of the mode to add to the list.

Comment: Its `latex-mode`  ; using `latex-mode` instead of `LaTeX-mode` solved it